# Retrieve a property from an HttpResponseMessage which was created in a POST method, which sent the request to RabbitMQ queue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microservices

This is my scenario.

I've created an ASP.NET Web APi solution with numerous microservices to process orders from a shopping cart.When posting an order consisting of a Guid identifier of a shopping cart, and a customer name, instead of posting immediately to an EF Core database, I put the request into a RabbitMQ queue. This POST method is supposed to

```
return Created("", new { orderId = returnedOrder.OrderGUID })
```

that is, an object containing the orderGUID as it is in the database. Let me say first, that through this long chain of microservices, I have no problems reading into the database, the order ends up there as it should.

Another service, OrderProcessor, consumes the process from the (RabbitMQ)ueue, and sends it to the OrderManager, which is responsible for reading into the database through DbContext. The register method there is void, since I see no reason to return anything from it. It simply creates the Order object from a DTO model, and uses Context.Add and Context.SaveChanges to do it's job.

My problem is this.

The original POST method, which places the order in the queue, returns Accepted() to the HttpResponseMessage in the API Gateway, which is received in the HttpPost method. It seems to me, the Guid of the newly created order record in the database, is nowhere to be found in the received response message.

Even if I could put something as parameters into Accepted(), what would be the point? When the POST method is sending to the RabbitMQ queue, it has no idea what will be the order Guid when it is placing the request into the queue. The OrderGUID is the primary identity key of the Order record, created in the database.

Simply put, how can I, or can I even, get the order Guid into the latter POST method, the one which receives the request in the Postman request originally, or any request source, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by creating a new column in the order table, which can be set directly unlike an ID, which is created at database insert time. That new column could then be set directly in the DTO (data transfer object) models and read manually into the database record.

Which means I can return the new column Guid, as a response in the API Gateway controller's HttpPost method. Had to rebuild the database, but that still was quicker than having to scratch my head countless hours how to go about it the other way.